# Akka Child Actor life cycle

Tags: akka, akka-http

all I some question for Akka child actor life cycle.

I know that the lifespan of a child actor cannot be longer than that of a parent actor.

In this case child actor will exit?

CASE

**If the parent actor exits while the child actor is working, will the child actor abandon the job he is processing and the job he is planning to handle and exit?**

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/actor-lifecycle.html#stopping-actors)

> A child actor can be forced to stop after it finishes processing its
> current message by using the stop method of the ActorContext from the
> parent actor. Only child actors can be stopped in that way.

In other words, the child does finish the current message (if it is processing one). (It would be hard to do otherwise without killing the thread and that has lots of problems.) Essentially a flag is set that will break out of the loop that processes messages.

After the current message, however, the actor will stop, abandoning its mailbox. You still have opportunity to clean up in a PostStop, however.

Comment: Thank u, for u r comment. it is helpful for me.